# Source that Leah was veiled at her wedding?

Tags: clothing, wedding, imahot-matriarch-mothers, vayeitzei, face

I know it seems obvious that Leah was wearing some sort of facial covering during the wedding which is what allowed Yaakov to mistake her for Rochel, however I can't find any source in chazal or the rishonim which says so explicitly. For example [Rashi on Bereshis 29:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8224#showrashi=true&v=25), also in [Megilah 13b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=13b&format=pdf) discusses the giving over of signs, but doesn't mention a veil.

What is the source that Leah wore a veil at her wedding to Yaakov?

Comment: Perhaps as you say, that Yaakov did not see that it was Leah until after they woke up in the morning.

Comment: @sabbahillel but I can concoct any number of scenarios to explain that. Who says their weddings worked like ours? Perhaps Yaakov did not see her at all until then?

Comment: @sabbahillel But Kiddushin may have been via Shaliach. Or it was night time. Or she wore lots of makeup. Or..

Comment: The _Tol'dos Yitzchak_ (by _Rav Yitzchak_ Karo, uncle of the _Bes Yosef_) **may** be implying the contrary (viz, that she didn't wear a veil). Specifically, he writes that, unlike _Lot_ who fed his guests _matza_, _Lavan_ made the wedding feast only-wine-based ([29:22](http://chabad.org/8224#v=22)), which was in order to get _Yaakov_ so drunk he'd not know whom he was marrying.

Comment: Not just a veil is claimed: according to http://www.torahtots.com/parsha/breishis/vayet2.htm, http://www.tziporahheller.com/letter-on-rachel-imeinu/, and other online sources, it was an especially thick veil.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=QYdAAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22travels+in+persia%22&pg=PA61 is the earliest source for a veil that I've found *so far*. It's Christian.

Comment: The _Midrash Raba_ **may** be implying the contrary (viz, that she didn't wear a veil). Specifically, it writes (70:19) that the lights were extinguished for the wedding in order to deceive _Yaakov_.

Comment: @msh210 - I can't find a single primary source to back that claim. Including Torah Shlema and the Medrash Raba and Shimoni. But see my6 proposed answer.

Comment: People often fail to state the obvious, I'm not sure that we can expect any sources to state explicitly that a veil was worn so long as this was generally done.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, agreed, hence my answer

Answer (score 5):

The Medrash Raba [פרשה ע](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01633_part_7.html#%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%94B%D7%A2-%D7%99%D7%97) uses the phrase:

> בְּרַמְשָׁא אֲתוֹן **מַעֲלָתָא** וַחֲפוֹן בּוֹצִינַיָא.‏

All  the Meforshim translate that as "at night the **lads** came and turned off [lit. covered] the lights."

The exact spelling of מַעֲלָתָא is a matter of dispute. See the various Meforshim on the Medrash Raba. E.g. The Yalkut Shimoni (כ"ט כ"ב-כ"ה) says **מטליתא** which sounds like a **cloth**.

Conceivable one could translate it as "at night they brought a **veil** and [also] covered the lights."

Comment: BTW: I asked various Darshanim, and none of them had ever heard that Leah wore a veil. I just emailed Rebbetzin Heller for her source.

Answer (score 2):

Professor James A. Diamond of the University of Waterloo provides several academic sources in [his paper](https://www.academia.edu/4822884/The_Deception_of_Jacob_A_New_Perspective_on_an_Ancient_Solution_to_the_Problem_Author_s_J) on how Lavan tricked Yaakov (his answer is basically veil + inebriation). These sources in turn claim that veiling the bride was a common practice in that place at that time, none cite the works of Chazal or the Rishonim in support for this contention.