# is there an actual source associating the bridal veil (hinuma) with the story of yaakov and leah?

Tags: minhag

Is there an actual source associating the bridal veil (**hinuma**) with the story of Yaakov and Leah??

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/kallahs-veil-under-chupah
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48580/source-that-leah-was-veiled-at-her-wedding

Comment: If there wasn’t something covering her face then Yaakov would definitely had known she was Leoh, and everyone else at the wedding (their entire family)